# How can I set up a (GUI) local version control system on my Mac?

Tags: version-control

I'm a web developer. My company has a dev server that all of us work directly on. There's only 3 of us, all working on different projects, so there's no issue with people overwriting each other's work. Because we're so small, no one has set up any kind of version control, and I'm not in a position to insist on it for all of us. However, I recently broke some of my own code and can't get it working again, and this makes me want to set up some kind of version control.

Here's how I'd like this to work:

1. Make a local copy of my project that exists on the dev server.
2. Make changes on the dev server.
3. After every major change, commit to my local copy.
4. If the new change broke the code on the dev server, be able to grab the previous version from the local copy.

Because I'm frequently working in 6 or more files at a time, it's not feasible for me to just manually create backups of each file before making any changes.

I've looked at GitBox and Versions, but am unable to tell if either of them will allow me to make a local copy of a remote project that isn't using some kind of version control.

Does anyone have suggestions for a good GUI version control system for Macs that will let me accomplish what I've outlined above? (The main issue is step #1 - making a local copy of a project that isn't already using a version control system and being able to update the local copy with a single action.)

Comment: Voted to migrate to StackOverflow.com.

Comment: Seems like a normal software solution with no actual programming involved, I guess it's fine to stay here @techie

Comment: @slhck - I see what you're saying, but SO covers code questions as well as questions regarding "•software tools commonly used by programmers" and "•matters that are unique to the programming profession".  I think version control falls into these, and she'll probably get a better answer over there (if there isn't a similar question already). :)

Comment: How do you connect to the server? Is it mapped locally and shows up as a drive, or do you FTP into it? Also, is rsync available?

Comment: @Alan - I can connect to the server several ways - SFTP, via a Transmit mapping (allows you to map an FTP server to your Mac finder so you can use it like a local drive), and also via my editor (Komodo allows you to set up SFTP connections and then browse/work on files on the remote drive as if they were local.) I'm not sure what rsync is...

Comment: @EmmyS - rsync is basically a smart copy command on steroids. It's great for pretty much any type of sync or copy you need to do. Well worth looking into. I've added another answer that uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the mapping available via (Transmit)[http://www.panic.com/transmit/] you can pretty easily do what you are looking for.

One option that would give you the GUI interface is just to copy the files manually each time and then use GitBox to create a new commit each time you wanted to store a set of changes. That would work, but it would get tedious quickly. Tedious stuff gets neglected so not the best option.

A better solution would be to setup a little script that would do the copy and commit for you. Check out the following as an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

### SETUP:

### Set the path to the remote mapped directory
SOURCE="/Volumes/your/mapped/folder/path"

### Set the path to your local folder (this must already exist)
REPOS="/Users/your-username/your-storage-folder"


### MAIN:

### Move into the respository directory
cd $REPOS

### Initialize the repository if it doesn't exist
if [ ! -d "${REPOS}/.git" ]; 
    then 
    git init
fi

### Now copy down the files
rsync -a --delete --exclude '.git' $SOURCE/ $REPOS/

### Add all the changes to git staging
git add .

TIMESTAMP=`date`

### Now commit the changes
git commit -am "Committed: $TIMESTAMP"
```

Assuming you have git installed on your mac, that should work if you:

- Create a new text file with a ".command" extension (e.g. "archive-site.command") and paste that code into it.
- Change the "SOURCE" and "REPOS" paths to the values to actual paths on your machine.
- Use `chmod u+x archive-site.command` to allow it to be executable.

From there, all you would have to do is double click on that file in the Finder and it'll sync your local folder with the contents of the server's directory and then make a new commit in the repository. It's basic and a bit unorthodox, but it will give you a some level of version control protection without too much hassle.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it would do exactly what I need to do (until I can convince the powers-that-be that real version control is a good idea even for a department of 2...) I'll give it a shot later this week when I have a few minutes to play.

Comment: Alan - I hope you're still watching this. I appreciate all the help so far and hope you can give a little more... So I set up your script and ran it once, and it did copy down all of the code from my dev server directory. However, after it was complete, I went onto the dev server and added a few lines of code to one file, then ran the script again. Instead of copying down the changes, it just tells me that there's nothing to commit. How do I get it to pull down changes?

Comment: OK, to update this: it seems the issue is not with the script, but with the mounted volume. I made a change to a file, but when I look at the mounted volume in Finder, it doesn't show a change to the Date Modified. If I disconnect the volume and remount, then it shows the change. I really like the idea of your script, but if the date doesn't update in Finder it's not going to work.

Comment: Shame that the mount isn't keeping you. You can also try using rsync to connect to the server directly. To do that, change the SOURCE variable to hit the server itself (e.g. devserver.yourcompany.com:/full/path/to/dir/from/root). That should go over ssh, which should work since you are hitting the server via SFTP already. The difference is that if you don't have ssh keys setup, it'll ask you for your password. (I'm going from memory here, I don't think you need to change anything else. Give it a shot and we'll see.)

Comment: Thanks again for the hand-holding, Alan. I actually emailed Transmit's developers to see if there was anything that could be done to force the update. Haven't heard back yet, so I tried your suggestion of hitting the server directly. I'm not sure what ssh keys are, but it did ask for a password. The problem is, the username it automatically used is my computer's username, which is not the same as my SSH access username. From what I can tell, ssh keys will generate keys using your computer username, which doesn't help. Is there any way to store the correct username/pw in the script file?

Comment: Change the SORUCE path to add the username that you have on the server. (e.g. emmys@devserver.yourcompany.com:/full/path/to/dir/from/root). Once you confirm that works, this is a decent intro to SSH keys: http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/. You won't need to install OpenSSH, it's already on the Mac.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! You are a rock star. I can just use this each time I make a change that passes all my tests. Then if I make a change that breaks something, I can just go back to the version that's saved in my local repository.

Comment: Happy to help. Welcome to the increased sense of security that comes with knowing you're code is inside a version control system.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO: Just 2 people is enough to justify a source code control for the group.  If the others are unwilling then the next best thing is to cover your behind...

Set up a local repository in whatever system you prefer.  Then copy the app off the remote server and ADD it to version control.  Since other people may make changes without your knowledge, you should start each edit session by comparing your local copy to the development one.

You may want to look into `rcp` for maintaining your local copy against the development one.

It may be helpful to keep TWO local copies, one you work on and one that you use to merge in changes from the development copy.  Just overwrite the files in the local dev copy with the ones for development.  Then check them in or merge as necessary.  This will allow you to do a complete compare of changes in dev against your repo without killing your own working copy.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your situation (and couldn't get a version control system setup on the server) I would change the methodology you propose to something more like this:

*Note: I realize you are asking about a GUI, but I'm going to put in the commands you could use in the terminal here too. It is actually pretty easy to do. With just a few minutes practice and a little cheat sheet, you'll probably find it easier/faster to do it that way. I'm also assuming that your dev web server is a linux/unix type and that you can setup your mac to server web pages in a similar way. Either via the built in web sharing feature or with something like [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html).*

1. Create an empty local working directory on my Mac that will be used to do the development work.
2. Initialize a git repository from the Terminal app in the local working directory with:

   ```
   git init
   ```
3. Pull down all the code from the dev server to the local working directory. I would do this with the rsync command from the terminal. If you have the dev server mounted as a drive on your mac, the command would be something like:

   ```
   rsync -a /Volumes/{DriveName}/{path}/{to}/{project-folder} /Users/{yourUserName}/projects/{project-folder}
   ```

   If the drive isn't mounted, you can probably still use rsync. It'll just take a different setup. There's other resources available for helping with that if you need them. Of course, you can also use whatever else you were planning to transfer the files with in your workflow.

   As a more direct point to your question, I'm not aware of git or other version control software being able to pull files from a remote location that's not another repository. I think you are going to have to do this step with something else.
4. Add all the files to git so it knows to track them and then commit them into the repository with:

   ```
   git add .
   git commit -m "Put a commit message here"
   ```
5. Make whatever changes you need to the files on the Mac instead of on the dev server using either the built in Mac Web Sharing or something like MAMP to view the changes.
6. Add all the changes and commit again with the same two commands:

   ```
   git add . 
   git commit -m "A new message about what changed"
   ```
7. Repeat steps 5 and 6 until you have something you want to ship back up to the dev server for more in depth testing.
8. Push your code up to the dev server. Then go back to step 5 and continue to make changes and commits until you are ready to push back up to dev again.

Benefits of this approach:

- It'll be a lot easier to deal with the version control locally than trying to copy files down each time and then version. Doing it that way would require extra steps that means it's more likely that a mistake will occur or you won't do it as much as you should.
- It should be faster than working on the dev server itself.
- You can work even when you aren't connected to the dev server. (If your machine is some type of macbook, you can work from anywhere.)
- You are much less likely to ever have the dev server in a state where your code isn't working.
- No one will see your code unless it's in a state that you are ready for them to see.

This workflow provides basic versioning that lets you simply roll back to prior versions. There's more you can do with branches, tagging, etc... but what I laid out will get you started with the basics and cover you as often as you make commits. In terms of the GUI, you mentioned GitBox. I've used that before and like it, but I've found that it's a lot easier and quicker for me to use the commands on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately I can't feasibly do my development locally (even with MAMP.) It's a Drupal site that relies on several huge (100+ tables, 500,000+ records each) databases within the Drupal install, plus external databases and code from another internal system. It's just too complicated a setup to try to make a complete local replica of the system.

Comment: Gotcha. If it's that big, I would try to suggest that it's worth setting up version control on the server itself. You don't have to insist on it, but use your example of getting code into a non-working state and not being able to roll back as an example of a problem that can easily be solved with git or the like. My pitch would basically be: "Everyone makes mistakes, but with just a little work, we can provide a lot of protection from them costing us significant time." Totally worth a shot unless there is some huge office politics reason not to.